# ion-range disabled when I want to select 0

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have an ion-range where the user can select a value between 0 and 10. I would like to require the user to select a value before going further for I use `[disabled]` I'd like the user to be able to give a value between 0 and 10. But since I required the user to select something, it it impossible to select 0. In fact, the value is by default 0, so when the user move it (to 1 or more), the button become active but if he comes back to 0 it's impossible to send the result.

```
  <div *ngFor="let q of questions">
  <h2>{{q.text}}</h2>
  <ion-item >
      <ion-range min='0' max='10' pin="true" [(ngModel)]="q.answer" >
          <ion-label slot="start">0</ion-label>
          <ion-label slot="end">10</ion-label>
      </ion-range>
    </ion-item>
      <ion-button [disabled]='(q.required && !q.answer)' (click)="getAnswer()">Submit</ion-button>
  </div>
```

.ts file :

```
  questions = [
    {
      id: 1,
      text : 'test',
      required: true,
      answer: ''
    }
  ];

  getAnswer() {
    console.log(this.questions);
  }
```

[image]

So `Submit` is disabled, if I move it, it becomes active but if I come back to 0 it comes back again on disabled... I'd like the user to be able to select 0 but force him to at least make a move...

**TD;DR / Expected Behavior**

Initially the default value of `ion-range` is set to `0` and the `submit` button is `disabled`. I want to enable the `submit` button if the user selects a value manually. Even if the user manually sets the value of `ion-range` to `0`.

Comment: not exactly, I want to disabled the button until the user did not move it, but I would like the user to be able to select 0 to 10 (all the possible value). Actually since I disabled it at 0, it's impossible to select 0... The solution you are saying is actually working. I can send 1 to 10 but not 0...

Comment: Initially the default value of `ion-range` is set to `0` and the `submit` button is `disabled`. You want to enable the `submit` button even if the use manually sets the value of `ion-range` to `0`. is this it?

Comment: yes exactly, the user can send 0 but he has to move it before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a flag to determine if the user touched the ion-range. Set a `ionFocus` event like this -

```
  <div *ngFor="let q of questions">
  <h2>{{q.text}}</h2>
  <ion-item >
      <ion-range min='0' max='10' pin="true" [(ngModel)]="q.answer" (ionFocus)="onTouch()">
          <ion-label slot="start">0</ion-label>
          <ion-label slot="end">10</ion-label>
      </ion-range>
    </ion-item>
      <ion-button [disabled]='(q.required && !q.answer && !wasTouched)' (click)="getAnswer()">Submit</ion-button>
  </div>
```

And in the typescript file -

```
...
export class DemoPage {

  ...
  wasTouched = false;

  ...
  touched() {
    this.wasTouched = true;
  }
}
```